# How can I apply a Metro style to the Page Control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm working on a project with WPF using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I'm trying to use an style similar to Visual Studio Dark Theme and this article [Visual Studio 2012 Metro Styles for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-Metro-Styles-for-WPF) helped me to achieve this. I am setting up a style for Menu, Button, ComboBox, DataGrid, ScrollBar, TextBox and others, but for the control Page I don't found a way to get in Metro Style.

[image]

This is my app.xaml

```
Application x:Class="Chem.Managment.Visual.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.Core;component/MetroWindowResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.Tooltip.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.Core;component/Resources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/MenuStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/ComboBoxStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/DataGridStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/GroupBoxStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/ScrollBarStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/TextBoxStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/WindowStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ChemResDict.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardButton}"/>
            <Style TargetType="Window" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardWindow}"/>
            <Style TargetType="Menu" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardMenu}"/>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardScrollBar}"/>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardTextBox}"/>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardDataGrid}"/>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardComboBox}"/>
            <Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardGroupBox}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

I tried to add the page control in the code above but I don't know how, maybe it is not implemented.

What am I missing here? Any suggestion please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The style for `Pages` is defined in `Controls.Page.xaml` wich is referenced from `Controls.xaml`. As I check your resources you do not import none of the previously mentioned resources. According to the documentation of `MahApps` you have to include the following resources in order to have the full `MahApps` experience:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

As theme you can use `BaseLight.xaml` or `BaseDark.xaml`, as accent you find any possible color on [GitHub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents).